# How to replace strings in multiple file using Python

Tags: python, shell

I have two files (say file1 and file2). There are strings in file1 and file2 (equal numbers of strings).

I want to search the content of file1 in a directory(which have multiple sub-directories and XML files) which contains XML files and replace it with the content for file2.

```
import subprocess
import sys
import os
f_line = f.readlines()
g_line = g.readlines()
f=open("file1.txt")
g=open("file2.txt")

i = 0
for line in f_line:
    if line.replace("\r\n", "") != g_line[i].replace("\r\n", "") :
        print (line)
        print(g_line[i])
        cmd = "sed -i 's/" + line.replace("\r\n", "") + "/" + line[i].replace("\r\n","") + "/g' " + "`grep -l -R " + line.replace("\r\n", "") + " *.xml`"
        print(cmd)
        os.system(cmd)
    i = i + 1
```

But the problem I'm facing is like this. The script searches the files and string and prints also (print(cmd)) but when I sun this script placing in the directory, I see this error in CYGWIN window "no input files for sed".

Comment: This question makes very little sense.  Can you provide example input, out, and what you have done already?

Comment: @Derek

file1           
harry
shoot
raj

file2
care
poor
dear

now i want to search string "harry" of file1 in the some directory (myfolder/project/) and replace with string of file 2 "care" and so on.

did i make my point clear?

Comment: @harry you should edit your question to add the contents of your comment.

Comment: See open here http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open , readlines here http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html, os.walk here http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html and re.sub here http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: also, for kicks, you might want sed http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

Comment: @tcaswell thankx.. now i have edited my question..i m new to stackoverflow so didnt know where to edit..

Comment: @Himanshu i have posted my script can you look and see what is going wrong there?

Comment: @harry see the output of the print cmd . Run it without the script

Comment: @harry if you have sed why use python at all. Combine the two files using paste file1 file2 > file . Make file into a sed script and run it over all the files using find dirname -name '*.xml' -exec file "{}" .

Comment: @Himanshu the script you gave is not working.
i tried using Shell script using find and sed command but it didnt work for me so i tried using python and shell combinedly

Comment: @Himanshu i dont know why but somehow sed is not working .. i verified in cmd window also

Comment: What is the output of print cmd i.e. what is the sed cmd you tried and which didn't work. btw what are the errors you see with the script :)

Comment: for your script i see nothing ..no error..nothing..

Comment: when i run sed in cmd window i see it doesnot find .xml files thoush they are present there :(

Comment: sed -i 's/" + abcd + "/" + efgf+ "/g' " + "`grep -l -R " + abcd+ " *.xml`" 

in same directory

Comment: Make that command find dirname -name '*.xml' -exec sed -i s/abcd/efgh/g "{}" \;

Comment: @Himanshu
i tried this and now it seems to work fine..

cmd = "result = `grep -R -l -i -e " + abcd + "` *; if [ \"$result\" != '' ];then sed -i 's/" + abcd + "/" + efgh +"/g'  $result; fi"

Answer (score 1):

read two files into a dictionary

walk the directory reading xml files, replacing their contents, backing them up and overwriting the originals

```
f1 = open('pathtofile1').readlines()
f2 = open('pathtofile2').readlines()
replaceWith = dict()
for i in range(len(f1)):
    replaceWith[f1[i].strip()] = f2[i].strip()

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('pathtodir'):
    for f in filenames:
        f = open(os.path.join(root, f), 'r')
        contents = f.read()
        for k, v in replaceWith:
            contents = re.sub(k, v, contents)
        f.close()
        shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(root, f), os.path.join(root, f)+'.bak')
        f = open(os.path.join(root, f), 'w')
        f.write(contents)
        f.close()
```

A limitation is that if some search strings appear in replacements strings, a string may be replaced many times over.